# Custom ID of Sharepoint Item

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am developing a discussion board in sharepoint but in that I require to have a custom ID field for each sharepoint list item and item ID should be like appended with current year "2012-1","2012-2" etc...

let me add that ... if the year changes then I would need to start the IDs from 1 for that year like if 2013 comes then the IDs will be like 2013-1,2013-2 etc.

Please share your suggestions

Thanks
Rhm

Answer (score 1):

Someone asked this [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094628/sharepoint-calculated-column-values-disappear-when-editing-list-item-any-ideas) and the answer was to create simple workflow. Probably  event receiver would work too, if you're more familiar with them.

Answer (score 1):

ItemEventReceiver is the way to go I think. Hereby the link to an example on how to do it:
http://dlairman.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/autonumbering-event-handler/

Answer (score 0):

Despite seeing everywhere that you cannot reference the ID column in a calculated column I had no problem doing so(In SharePoint Online). Make a calculated column and for the formula use =ID (Whatever formula you would like to use). For instance I needed to start at 5000 so I used =ID + 5000, keeping the unique property of an ID field but being able to start it where you want.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

The ID cannot be changed. You can however create a calculated column that uses the ID in it's value.

Comment: ok, please tell me how to get current Year and concatenate to custom ID column

Comment: You cannot use ID in calculated column. You can try this and see what happens: =YEAR(Created)&"-"&ID

Hint: ID isn't populated when you create the item, only after you add it, or if you modify the calculated column.

Comment: Whoa, didn't even know that! (after 6 yrs of working with sharepoint, it still has secrets :-D). So that would mean you'd need to  create something like an ItemEventReceiver to get my proposed behavior....